# Как скомпилировать SQLITE c новым параметром SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN?

Tags: c, sqlite, sqlite3

Никак не могу скомпилировать новую сборку SQLITE.

Сначала скажу зачем мне это нужно: снять ограничение 2000 столбцов в SQLite. Мне нужно установить 3000 столбцов. Я знаю, что это можно сделать, ограничение SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN < 32767 столбцов.

Есть официальный туториал с сайта sqlite.org  [2. Compiling The Command-Line Interface](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html)

Я начал с него. Дело в том, что SQLITE написан на языке `C`. Надо скомпилировать исходные файлы. Компилировать будем через GCC компилятор [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/). Устанавливал GCC по туториалу [metanit](https://metanit.com/cpp/c/1.2.php). Скачиваем с официального сайт sqlite файл [sqlite-amalgamation-3390300.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Итого Имеем 4 файла:

- sqlite3.c: The SQLite amalgamation source file
- sqlite3.h: The header files that accompanies sqlite3.c and defines the C-language interfaces to SQLite.
- shell.c  The command-line interface program itself.
- sqlite3ext.h

Я перебрал все возможные команды для GCC компилятора.

1. Команда 1

Пробовал эту как указано в оф. справке:

> gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl -lm -o sqlite3

не работает и выдает

```
cannot find -Idl:No such file or directory
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как понимаю, он его не находит в папке с компилятором GCC. Зачем нужен `-Idl` я так и не понял.

2. Команда 2

Вычитал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096246/sqlite3-increase-max-columns), что можно поменять параметр SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN в файле `sqlite3.c`, что я и сделал. Далее убрал `-Idl`. Применил команду

```
gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -lm -o sqlite3
```

Создал `sqlite3.exe`. Запускаем его и сохраняем БД командой `.save nameDB.db`
Получаем в итоге файл базы данных SQLite.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иду в ожиданиях результата и тестирую запрос sql на добавление 3000 столбцов. Получаю печальный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Команда 3

Хорошо, думаю тогда модернизирую команду с официального сайта и добавлю параметр
`-DSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=32767`

Тогда команда будет

```
gcc -DSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=32767 shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -lm -o sqlite3
```

Создался `sqlite3.exe` и результат такой же. Опять больше 2000 не добавляет.

4. Команда 4

Тогда я решил попробовать команду указанную в посте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096246/sqlite3-increase-max-columns)

> gcc -I. -O3 -DSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=32767 -c sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o

В итоге создается файл sqlite3.o с которым не понятно что вообще делать. Там в пункте 4 сказано, что нужно создать статическую библиотеку и сопоставить с этими файлами, но я не очень понимаю, что именно нужно сделать. Ведь мне нужно получить в итоге файл базы данных `.db`

В итоге все команды и методы, что использовал, не помогли. Прошу знающих подсказать, как скомпилировать SQLite сняв ограничение на количество столбцов в ней и получить файл базы данных, с которым можно работать.

Comment: Не вникал в текст вопроса, но не факт что изменение макроса реально повлияет на лимит. Лучше гляньте место в коде которое выводит сообщение, что столбцов слишком много.